# How to check LineString against R-Tree index in Rust?

Tags: rust, geospatial, r-tree

I have a few points, and a lot of linestrings, and I want to find all combinations of linestring & point within X metres. But I can't find suitable crates for this.

For example [rstar crate](https://docs.rs/rstar/latest/rstar/) implements an R-Tree index. But it works only with one type: if the tree is made of ([geo](https://docs.rs/geo/latest/geo/index.html)) [Points](https://docs.rs/geo/latest/geo/geometry/struct.Point.html), it can't run methods against [LineStrings](https://docs.rs/geo/latest/geo/geometry/struct.LineString.html) (see the [example](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b#%2F*%0A%5Bdependencies%5D%0Ageo%20%3D%20%270.23%27%0Arstar%20%3D%20%270.9%27%0A%0A*%2F%0A%0Ause%20rstar%3A%3ARTree%3B%0Ause%20geo%3A%3Ageometry%3A%3A%7BLineString%2C%20Point%2C%20Coordinate%7D%3B%0Ause%20geo%3A%3Aline_string%3B%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%09let%20mut%20rt%20%3D%20RTree%3A%3Abulk_load(vec!%5BPoint(Coordinate%3A%3Afrom((0.1%2C%200.1)))%2C%20Point(Coordinate%3A%3Afrom((10.0%2C%2010.0)))%5D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20l%20%3D%20line_string!%5B(x%3A%2010.0%2C%20y%3A%200.0)%2C%20(x%3A%2010.0%2C%20y%3A%2020.0)%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20rt.nearest_neighbor(%26l))%3B%0A%7D%0A) in Rust Explorer that doesn't compile).

Is there any way to use **rstar** or a working crate for this?

The only way around I see is to make a bounding box from the LineString and call [`RTree::locate_in_envelope`](https://docs.rs/rstar/latest/rstar/struct.RTree.html#method.locate_in_envelope), and then calculate the distance from points to the linestring manually.

```
/*
[dependencies]
geo = '0.23'
rstar = '0.9'

*/

use rstar::RTree;
use geo::geometry::{LineString, Point, Coordinate};
use geo::line_string;

fn main() {
    let mut rt = RTree::bulk_load(vec![Point(Coordinate::from((0.1, 0.1))), Point(Coordinate::from((10.0, 10.0)))]);
    let l = line_string![(x: 10.0, y: 0.0), (x: 10.0, y: 20.0)];
    println!("{:?}", rt.nearest_neighbor(&l));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a bit more research, I found crate [`spatial-join`](https://docs.rs/spatial-join/latest/spatial_join/), but it's been unmaintained for 2 years. It doesn't compile with the newest [`geo`](https://docs.rs/geo/latest/geo/) crate.

Looking into its implementation, it's using the same R-Tree, so probably with some work, I can re-implement this.